# Error : expected body of lambda expression .. (what is Lambda ???)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Just start learning CS106B , Error messages telling me something wrong with these 3 lines.

" Error : expected body of lambda expression "

string key = aToken.substr([i],1);

myMap.put(aToken.substr([i],1),1);

else {myMap[aToken.substr([i],1)] +=1};

```
int main() {

TokenScanner myTK;
myTK.setInput("Sven is Pro Moo Noob <naja>");
myTK.ignoreWhitespace();
Map <string ,int> myMap;
while(myTK.hasMoreTokens()){
    string aToken = myTK.nextToken();
    for(int i=0;i<= int(aToken.size());i++){
        string key = aToken.substr([i],1);
        if(!myMap.containsKey(key)){
                myMap.put(aToken.substr([i],1),1);
        }
        else {myMap[aToken.substr([i],1)] +=1};
    }
    cout << aToken << endl;
}
cout<< myMap.toString() << endl;
return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expression is expression that usually takes form:

```
[capture list](parameters) {function body}
```

When compiler notices your `[i]` it expects that it's beginning of lambda expression. There is no reason to wrap numbers in square brackets in your case.

Lambda expressions allow in-line construction of functor objects with anonymous class. See: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)